# Need script to change div background via input

Tags: jquery, input, background-color

When I go back and erase the data leaving the input field blank, the background does not go back to it's original color UNLESS I TYPE A "0".

I need the background color of the DIV to revert back to its original color when blank.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#id").keypress(function() {
        if ($("#id").val().length > 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
        else {
            if ($("#id").val().length == 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "grey");
        }
    });

});​
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you testing the `.length` a second time? That's what the `else` is for.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you are using `keypress` which is called before the action of the key is executed. If you used `keyup` this will work:

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    else {
        $("#in").css("background-color", "grey");
    }
});
```

Also, as @mblase75 pointed out, you do not need to test the `length` of the value in the else condition.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAL4C/1/)

If you wanted to simplify this code even further, you can simply use a ternary statement with `.val().length` as the condition, as a positive integer will equate to true:

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $(this).val().length ? "red" : "grey");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use `keyup` to account for the character that was just entered:

```
$(function(){
    $("#id").keyup(function() {
        $("#in").css("background-color", $(this).val().length > 0 ? "red" : "grey");
     });
 });​
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgLVf/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: You've used `this` for both `#in` and `#id`.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work...

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#id").keyup(function() {
        if($("#id").val().length > 0) {
           $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
        }
        else {
           $("#in").css("background-color", "grey");
        }
    });
});​

</script>
```

Comment: I don't think `keypress` will work for what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, 'keypress' event has called before input.val().length changed.
And your code run selector retreiving five times, insted one.

Look to this code, it works fine:

html:

```
<input id="id" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<div class="in"></div>​​​
```

css:

```
.in {width:200px; height:20px; background-color:#grey;}
.in-red {background-color:red;}
```

​
js:

```
$(function(){
    var $in = $('.in');
    $('#id').on('keyup', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length > 0) {
            $in.addClass('in-red');
        } else {
            $in.removeClass('in-red');
        }
    });
});​
```

And you can test it on http://jsfiddle.net/Qhkev/1/

Answer (score -2):

Use keyup

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#id").keyup(function() {
    if($("#id").val().length > 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
  else {
    if($("#id").val().length == 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "grey");
 }

 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: If you vote down please comment why the vote down.  I tested this answer before posting and it works.